# How to find the column based on the minimum value and the position

Tags: group-by, powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

A new column should be added as a function of the condition.

Match Condition

1. eg : ID 1877
   1.) In the id group, the minimum value of tho_cw_diff should be checked and Rail position of thor_pos/CW_pos should be same.
2. eg : ID 7931
   2.) If the rail position is not the same for the minimum tho_cw_diff value, check for the other minimum value in group ID that the rail position thor_pos/CW_po is the same.
3. eg: ID 8880
   3.) If all the rail position is different for the group ID, select the minimum tho_cw_diff value.

According to these three conditions, the new column must be updated.

Sharing screenshot data of the expected outputs below

[image]

Comment: Please post data as text, not images.  We don't want to retype that to help you. Beyond that please explain what a rail position is.  And perhaps explain the rest of it as well. What are the exact comparisons that produce a yes or a no for a sample row

Comment: @horseyride Yes sure ! Rail position is (Left,Right) which is present in THO_poition & CW_pos . condition 1)  It should be same THO_poition  = CW_pos  with minimum THo_CW_Diff eg ID = 1877. condition 2) Have to check in the group of ID if the THO_poition  <>  CW_pos not equal to same with with minimum THO_CW_Diff then have to check another minimum difference from the group ID to check the same THO_poition  = CW_pos eg ID : 7931.condition 3) In the group ID all the THO_poition  and CW_pos are not equal then we go for the minimum THo_CW_Diff eg ID : 8880

Comment: Update your question and include copiable sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
VAR ID = [ID]
VAR CV_POS = [CV_POS]
VAR tmpTbl =
            CALCULATETABLE(
                 tbl
                 ,ALL()
                 ,tbl[ID] = ID
                 ,tbl[THO_position] = CV_POS
                 ,tbl[CV_POS] = CV_POS
            )
VAR Result =
    IF(
        ISEMPTY(tmpTbl)
       ,MIN(tbl[THO_CV_DIFF]) -- may be you can write just [THO_CV_DIFF]. I didn't check
       ,MINX(tmpTbl,[THO_CV_DIFF])          
     )     
RETURN
    Result
```

I didn't check, so come with a feedback.

By the way, you can add you table by using of following symbols: "|" and "-"

| myColumn1 | myColumn2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |

Comment: getting "NO" for all the result (Group ID's) and changed the code according to comments mentioned in the answer. please do the needful to get the expecting result

Comment: add a link to your *.pbix or *.pbix dummy